# HTML data-toggle="collapse" only collapse if it isn't already

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I want to collapse a div with a button if it is not collapsed already.
I have a button:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aim" ...></button>
```

and my `div`:

```
<div id="#aim" class="collapse"></div>
```

I works great but if the `div` is already open the button close it.

Is there a chance to get collapse it when it isn't already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `#` from your `<div id="#aim" class="collapse">` and it should work. More info about bootstrap's data-toggle attribute can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

(Previous comment added as possible answer to help close this question).

Answer (score 9):

My solution:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aim" ...></button>

<div id="aim" class="collapse in"></div>
```

so when you use `collapse in` instead of `collapse` it only expands and do not minimize itselfs again when it already expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript with on click and hide().

Comment: Remove the `#` from your `<div id="#aim" class="collapse">` and it should work. More info about bootstrap's data-toggle attribute can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

Comment: @PhilipScheer: Doh, wanted to attach my comment to your question, instead posted below the first answer. Could you add your solution below as a new answer and mark it as solution so the question is marked solved? Thanks!

Comment: @SaschaM78 how do i attach your comment to my Question? Just by editing my question?

Comment: @PhilipScheer I added my comment as new answer, if that solved your problem I would appreciate if you marked it as accepted answer. Thanks!